# bloc sink was called null

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc

I used imagePicker. I need to assign a profile photo after add. Last time I user setState() but not working.

**my bloc class look like this,**

```
class ImageBloc {
  final _loadingController = StreamController<String>();
  Stream<String> get loadingStream => _loadingController.stream;

  void setIsLoading(String image) => _loadingController.add(image);

  dispose() {
    _loadingController.close();
  }
}
```

**Player class**
This class is StatefullWidget

```
class _PlayersState extends State<Players> {
   ImageBloc bloc;
...
drawer: drawer(context, onProfilePictureChanged,bloc),
}
```

**drawer** this is a common drawer. I used this method in other class. other class, I passed null to bloc parameter

```
Widget drawer(BuildContext context, onProfilePictureChanged,ImageBloc bloc) {
  return Drawer(
    child: Container(child:
//I checked bloc null or not because others class I passed null value to bloc
                    bloc == null ? Text("null value",
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.white,
                        fontSize: 13.0,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                      )):
//Player class only I passed bloc
                    StreamBuilder<String>(
                      stream: bloc.loadingStream,
                        initialData: "bloc value",
                        builder: (context,snapshot){
                          return Text(snapshot.data,
                              style: TextStyle(
                                color: Colors.white,
                                fontSize: 13.0,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                              ));
                    }),))
```

**I passed bloc for set value to sink..**

```
 await showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (BuildContext context) {
          return ProfilePop(bloc:bloc);
        });
```

**ProfilePop class**

```
class ProfilePop extends StatefulWidget {
  const ProfilePop({Key key, @required this.bloc}) : super(key: key);
  final ImageBloc bloc;
}

class ProfilePopState extends State<ProfilePop>{

  upload(File imageFile) async {
   ...
      setState(() {
        global.profileImage = uploadedImage["Photo"];
        widget.bloc.setIsLoading(uploadedImage["Photo"]);
      });
...
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    void onCancelPressed() {
      Navigator.pop(context);
    }

    return new AlertDialog(
      title:global.image == null
                    ? profile
                    : new Container(
                       ...
                      ),
        ),
      ),);}
});}}
```

Answer (score 0):

i didn't see whether you initialize your bloc. For example, on Player class
the bloc passed to drawer is always null.

This setup you made is quite complex, maybe you should consider providing bloc using auxiliar packages like bloc_provider.

Comment: `Drawer` is common class for all pages.  How to change text on drawer when add image using alert?

Comment: Why bloc pass null?

Comment: You are kind of halfway there since. Since you are already using bloc and stream provider. You could sink your image onto your ImageBloc and get it on the stream provider snapshot.